# Push a button and have a random viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I'm very new to coding in Objective-C with Xcode, and I'm trying to be able to push a button and have the code pull up a random view controller.

I created classes for each of my view controllers and assigned them.

My viewcontroller.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)randomviewbutton {

    int randomview = rand() % 9;
    switch (randomview) {
        case 0:
            change.modalViewController = [UIViewController class:@"ViewController1"];
            break;
        case 1:
            change.modalViewController = [UIViewController class:@"ViewController2"];
            break;
        case 2:
            change.modalViewController = [UIViewController class:@"ViewController3"];
            break;
        case 3:
            change.modalViewController = [UIViewController class:@"ViewController4"];
            break;
        case 4:
            change.modalViewController = [UIViewController class:@"ViewController5"];
            break;
        case 5:
            change.modalViewController = [UIViewController class:@"ViewController6"];
            break;
        case 6:
            change.modalViewController = [UIViewController class:@"ViewController7"];
            break;
        case 7:
            change.modalViewController = [UIViewController class:@"ViewController8"];
            break;
        case 8:
            change.modalViewController = [UIViewController class:@"ViewController9"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

My viewcontroller.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIViewController *change;
}

-(IBAction)randomviewbutton;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to present a modal view controller using `-presentViewController:animated:completion:`, not by changing the `modalViewController` property directly.

Something like this:

```
-(IBAction)randomviewbutton {
    UIViewController *vc = nil;
    int randomview = rand() % 9;
    switch (randomview) {
        case 0:
            vc = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
        case 1:
            vc = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
        default:
            break;
    }
    [change presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```